# JS: topmost() is deprecated. Use Frame.topmost() instead

Tags: nativescript

I switched to Nativescript 6.3 and after that I have begun to get 
JS: topmost() is deprecated. Use Frame.topmost() instead. warning. And HMR does not to seem to make the instant changes as well. For navigation among pages I use the following
code:

```
 function onTap_StartPage() {
   var navigationEntry = {
    moduleName: "views/Sep-page/Sep-page",
    context:{trans:language,trans2:wordGroup},
    transition: {
        name: "fade",
        duration: 200,
    }
  };
 frames.topmost().navigate(navigationEntry);
 }
  exports.onTap_StartPage= onTap_StartPage;
```

What changes am I supposed to make? Just adding Frame before topmost() is not working as well.

```
 frames.Frame.topmost().navigate(navigationEntry);// is not working.
```

Then I tried navigation without topmost() and used the following:

```
 const getFrameById = require("tns-core    modules/ui/frame").Frame.getFrameById;
 const frame=getFrameById("myFrame" );
```

> `function onTap_StartPage() {
>       var navigationEntry = {
>           moduleName: "views/Sep-page/Sep-page",
>           context:{trans:language,
>               trans2:wordGroup,},
>           transition: {
>               name: "fade",
>               duration: 200,
>           }
>       };
>       frame.navigate(navigationEntry);
>   }
>   exports.onTap_StartPage= onTap_StartPage;`

Although navigation works I still get JS: topmost() is deprecated. Use Frame.topmost() instead. warning. and HMR is not working as well.

Comment: What you mean by **Frame.topmost() not working well**? Do you have multiple frames in your application?

Comment: Actually I only have one frame and navigation works but I get the - JS: topmost() is deprecated. Use Frame.topmost() instead.- warning. As a I mentioned above I removed all topmost() from my code but it still complains. And HMR is not working as well. I do not whether this is something related with topmost(). All happened after updating to Nativescript 6.3

Comment: You are on Core flavour right?

Comment: yes I am, and one more thing about HMR it only works on changes in AndroidManifest.xml, in other cases in console I see the following lines but nothing happens  -- Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done! thank you

Comment: I haven't had issues with HMR just because I use topmost. But HMR often have issues in specific scenario, you could disable it if you want so the app restarts everytime after changes.